# How do I vertically align multi-line chapter names in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

For multi-line chapter names in the TOC, how do I get the second and third lines to start in line with the first letter of the first word in the first line? Currently the second and third lines begin to the left of where I need them.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\def\chapter{\newpage\thispagestyle{plain}\secdef\CHAPa\CHAPb}

\def\CHAPa[#1]#2{%
\refstepcounter{chapter}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}
 \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{15pt}}
 \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{15pt}}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
   {\chaptername{\protect\ \thechapter: #1}}%
% \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
%   {\protect\numberline{\chaptername {\thechapter}:}#1}%
 \renewcommand{\KM}{#2}
 {{\centering  \chaptername\ \thechapter \par}
   { \centering #2\par}}
   \vspace{\baselineskip}}

\def\CHAPb#1{%
   { \centering #1\par}
    \vspace{\baselineskip}}

\newcommand{\KM}{Introduction}

\newcommand{\sectionThesis}[1]{\renewcommand{\KM}{\sf #1}\section{#1}}

\titlecontents{chapter}
[0pt]
{}%
{\contentsmargin{0pt}
    \thecontentslabel\enspace%
    }
{\contentsmargin{0pt}}
{\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{APPLICATION OF DISCRETE IT\^O FORMULAE TO A NONLINEAR STOCHASTIC DIFFERENCE EQUATION}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tocloft` instead of `titletoc` for a better result.

The relevant code is

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\newlength\mylength

\renewcommand\cftchapleader{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername~}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{:}
\settowidth\mylength{\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum}
\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylength}
```

[image]

Complete code (I've also changed a little your definition of `\CHAPa`):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\newlength\mylength

\renewcommand\cftchapleader{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername~}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{:}
\settowidth\mylength{\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum}
\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylength}

\def\chapter{\newpage\thispagestyle{plain}\secdef\CHAPa\CHAPb}

\def\CHAPa[#1]#2{%
 \refstepcounter{chapter}
 \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}
 \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{15pt}}
 \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{15pt}}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
 \renewcommand{\KM}{#2}
 {{\centering  \chaptername\ \thechapter \par}
   { \centering #2\par}}
   \vspace{\baselineskip}}

\def\CHAPb#1{%
   { \centering #1\par}
    \vspace{\baselineskip}}

\newcommand{\KM}{Introduction}

\newcommand{\sectionThesis}[1]{\renewcommand{\KM}{\sffamily #1}\section{#1}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{APPLICATION OF DISCRETE IT\^O FORMULAE TO A NONLINEAR STOCHASTIC DIFFERENCE EQUATION}

\end{document}
```

A similar result can be obtained with `titletoc` using the following settings:

```
\titlecontents{chapter}
[5.5em]
{}%
{\contentslabel{5.5em}}
{\hspace*{-5.5em}}
{\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage}
```

but the result is not so good:

[image]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\def\chapter{\newpage\thispagestyle{plain}\secdef\CHAPa\CHAPb}

\def\CHAPa[#1]#2{%
 \refstepcounter{chapter}
 \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}
 \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{15pt}}
 \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{15pt}}
% \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
%   {{\chaptername\ \thechapter: }#1}%
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
   {\protect\numberline{\chaptername\ \thechapter: }#1}%
 \renewcommand{\KM}{#2}
 {{\centering  \chaptername\ \thechapter \par}
   { \centering #2\par}}
   \vspace{\baselineskip}}

\def\CHAPb#1{%
   { \centering #1\par}
    \vspace{\baselineskip}}

\newcommand{\KM}{Introduction}

\newcommand{\sectionThesis}[1]{\renewcommand{\KM}{\sffamily #1}\section{#1}}

\titlecontents{chapter}
[5.5em]
{}%
{\contentslabel{5.5em}}
{\hspace*{-5.5em}}
{\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{APPLICATION OF DISCRETE IT\^O FORMULAE TO A NONLINEAR STOCHASTIC DIFFERENCE EQUATION}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I use the code with the `\tocloft` package in my MWE I get the following error messages: (i) undefined control sequence `\cftchapleader` -> `\cftdotfill` (ii) `\cftchappresum` undefined. Can you tell me how to fix these?

Comment: @PeterPalmer I don't know. Probably you have an out-to-date `tocloft` package. Does my MWE work fine for you?

Comment: Yes, the alignment is there but now the overall the layout has changed. That is, the word Chapter does not appear before the chapter number, the dots leading to the page number are not there anymore and the number 4.5 appears at the end of the chapter name.

Comment: @PeterPalmer Are you sure you've copied the code correctly?

Comment: Yes I did. I will update `\tocloft` and retry.

Comment: multiline toc entries often look better ragged right, and without hyphenation.  this avoids uneven interword spacing, and only rarely results in an additional line.

Comment: @karlkoeller It worked when I updated `\tocloft`. Thank you.

Comment: @barbarabeeton  Can you give some more explanation of what you are saying?